# Error: List (Error) Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to calculate Rn however I'm getting an error.

```js
var geometry = geometry;

Map.addLayer(geometry, {},"geometry");
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level0');

var Zim = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Zimbabwe'));
Map.addLayer(Zim, {}, 'Zim');

//Cold pixel location
var pt =ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(31.498292155037756,-21.003329144470932)).set('id',0);

Map.addLayer(pt, {}, 'pt');

var points_list = ee.List([pt]);

print('points_list', points_list); 

//all path/row
//[159,42], [159,43], [159,44], [160,42], [160,43], [160,44], 
//[161,42], [161,43], [161,44], [162,42], [162,43], [162,44]

//selected path/row [170,72]


//selected path/row [170,72]
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2023-01-01', '2024-01-01'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(Zim))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10));

var dataset_list =dataset.toList(dataset.size());

var pathRowList = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
  return[ee.Image(ele).get('WRS_PATH'),ee.Image(ele).get('WRS_ROW')];
}).distinct()
 .removeAll([[168,72], [168,73], [168,74], [168,75], [168,76], [169,71], [169,72], [169,73], [169,74],
 [169,75], [169,76], [170,71], [170,73],[170,74], [170,75], [171,71], [171,72],
 [171,73], [171,74], [171,75], [172,71], [172,72], [172,73], [172,74], [173,72], [173,73], [173,74]]);


  print("pathRowList", pathRowList);
  print("dataset list", dataset_list);
  print("dataset list size", dataset.size());


var createDataset = pathRowList.map(function(ele){
  
  var WRS_PATH = ee.List(ele).get(0);
  var WRS_ROW = ee.List(ele).get(1);
  
  var newDataset = ee.ImageCollection(dataset)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH',WRS_PATH))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW',WRS_ROW));
  return newDataset;
});

var createDataset = createDataset.map(function(ele){
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(ele).toList(ee.ImageCollection(ele).size());
});

print("Dataset subdivided by path and row",createDataset);

var newDataset = createDataset.map(function(ele){
 
  var dataset=ee.List(ele);
  dataset = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dataset);
  //select first image for determining geometry
  
  var image =dataset. first(0);
  var img_geom= ee.Image(image).geometry();
  
  //select main feature in uae for intersecting image geometry
  
  Zim = ee.FeatureCollection(Zim).geometry();
  
  //portion of Zim that intersects images in Image Collection
  
  var intersection = ee.Geometry(Zim).intersection(img_geom);
  
  //1. Compute the spectral radiance for each band (model F01)
  
  var dataset_list = dataset.toList(dataset.size());
  
  var band_list = ['B1', 'B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B9','B10','B11'];
  
  //map band_list for retrieving all parameters corresponding to RADIANCE_MULTI_BAND and RADIANCE_ADD_BAND
  //for calculating radiance from DN
  var parameters = band_list.map(function(ele){
  var idx = ee.Number(band_list.indexOf(ele)).add(1); // add 1 because it must start in 1 not 0
  
  var string1 =ee.String('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_').cat(ee.Number(idx).format());
  var string2 =ee.String('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_').cat(ee.Number(idx).format());
  return [ee.Image(image).select(ee.String(ele)).get(string1),
  ee.Image(image).select(ee.String(ele)).get(string2)];
  });
 
  dataset_list = ee.List(dataset_list).map(function(ele){
    
  var f1_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(0)).get(0);
  var f1_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(0)).get(1);
  var l1=ee.Image(ele).select('B1').multiply(ee.Number(f1_0)).add(ee.Number(f1_1)).rename('L1');
  
  var f2_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(1)).get(0);
  var f2_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(1)).get(1);
  var l2=ee.Image(ele).select('B2').multiply(ee.Number(f2_0)).add(ee.Number(f2_1)).rename('L2'); 
  
  var f3_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(2)).get(0);
  var f3_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(2)).get(1);
  var l3=ee.Image(ele).select('B3').multiply(ee.Number(f3_0)).add(ee.Number(f3_1)).rename('L3');
  
  var f4_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(3)).get(0);
  var f4_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(3)).get(1);
  var l4=ee.Image(ele).select('B4').multiply(ee.Number(f4_0)).add(ee.Number(f4_1)).rename('L4');
  
  var f5_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(4)).get(0);
  var f5_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(4)).get(1);
  var l5=ee.Image(ele).select('B5').multiply(ee.Number(f5_0)).add(ee.Number(f5_1)).rename('L5');
  
  var f6_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(5)).get(0);
  var f6_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(5)).get(1);
  var l6=ee.Image(ele).select('B6').multiply(ee.Number(f6_0)).add(ee.Number(f6_1)).rename('L6');
  
  var f7_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(6)).get(0);
  var f7_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(6)).get(1);
  var l7=ee.Image(ele).select('B7').multiply(ee.Number(f7_0)).add(ee.Number(f7_1)).rename('L7');
  
  var f8_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(7)).get(0);
  var f8_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(7)).get(1);
  var l8=ee.Image(ele).select('B8').multiply(ee.Number(f8_0)).add(ee.Number(f8_1)).rename('L8');
  
  var f9_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(8)).get(0);
  var f9_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(8)).get(1);
  var l9=ee.Image(ele).select('B9').multiply(ee.Number(f9_0)).add(ee.Number(f9_1)).rename('L9');
  
  var f10_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(9)).get(0);
  var f10_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(9)).get(1);
  var l10=ee.Image(ele).select('B10').multiply(ee.Number(f10_0)).add(ee.Number(f10_1)).rename('L10');
  
  var f11_0 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(10)).get(0);
  var f11_1 = ee.List(ee.List(parameters).get(10)).get(1);
  var l11=ee.Image(ele).select('B11').multiply(ee.Number(f11_0)).add(ee.Number(f11_1)).rename('L11');
  
  var bands = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11];
return ee.Image(ele).addBands(bands);
  
 
  });
  
  //2.Computing the reflectivity for each band (p_lambda) (model F02)
  
  // inverse squared relative earth-sun distance
  
  var dr =dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var DOY =ee.Number(ee.Date(ee.Image(ele).get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day','year')).add(1);
    
    var dr =ee.Number.expression (
      '1+0.033*cos(DOY*2*PI/365)',{
        'DOY':DOY,
        'PI':Math.PI
      });
    
    return dr;
  
  });
  
  //thermal bands are not considerated in reflectivity calculations for SEBAL approach
  //https://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/r/2016/01/26/estimating-landsat-8-esun-values
  //ESUNλ is the mean solar exo-atmospheric irradiance for each band (W/m 2 /μm)
  //           B1             B2             B3            B4              B5 
  //        1895.33        2004.57        1820.75        1549.49         951.76 
  //           B6              B7            B8            B9
  //         247.55          85.46        1723.88       366.97

  
  // Thermal bands 10 and 11 are not shortwave, so it is given a dummy value of 1 for ESUN
  
  var esun = [1895.33,2004.57,1820.75,1549.49,951.76, 247.55, 85.46, 1723.88,366.97,1,1];
  
  //ρλ = π * Lλ /(ESUNλ * cos θ * dr)   θ = 90 - SUN_ELEVATION    
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var idx = dataset_list.indexOf(ele);
    
    //reflectivity for B1
    var ref1 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L1'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(0))
      }).rename('ref1');
    //reflectivity for B2
    
      var ref2 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L2'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(1))
      }).rename('ref2');
    
    //reflectivity for B3
      var ref3 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L3'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(2))
      }).rename('ref3');
    
       //reflectivity for B4
      var ref4 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L4'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(3))
      }).rename('ref4');
    
      //reflectivity for B5
        var ref5 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L5'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(4))
      }).rename('ref5');
    
      //reflectivity for B6
        var ref6 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L6'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(5))
      }).rename('ref6');
    
     //reflectivity for B7
        var ref7 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L7'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(6))
      }).rename('ref7');
    
     //reflectivity for B8
        var ref8 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L8'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(7))
      }).rename('ref8');
    
     //reflectivity for B9
        var ref9 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L9'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(8))
      }).rename('ref9');
    
      //reflectivity for B10
        var ref10 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L10'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(9))
      }).rename('ref10');
    
      //reflectivity for B11
        var ref11 = ee.Image().expression(
      '(PI *L)/(esun * cos((90-beta)*PI/180)*dr)',
      {
        'L':ee.Image(ele).select('L11'),
        'PI':Math.PI,
        'dr':ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
        'beta':ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
        'esun':ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(10))
      }).rename('ref11');
    
    
    return ee.Image(ele).addBands([ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7,ref8,ref9,ref10,ref11]);
    
  });
  

 //3. Computing the albedo at the top of the atmosphere (atoa) (model F03)
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    //selecting reflectivity for each band
    var r1 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref1');
    var r2 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref2');
    var r3 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref3');
    var r4 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref4');
    var r5 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref5');
    var r6 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref6');
    var r7 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref7');
    var r8 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref8');
    var r9 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref9');
    var r10 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref10');
    var r11 = ee.Image(ele).select('ref11');
    
    //calculating sum of esun
    
    var sum_esun = ee.Number(ee.List(esun).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()));
    
    //calculating weighting coefficients for each band according to formula F9 
    
    var ome1 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(0)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome2 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(1)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome3 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(2)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome4 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(3)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome5 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(4)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome6 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(5)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome7 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(6)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome8 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(7)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome9 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(8)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome10 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(9)).divide(sum_esun);
    var ome11 =ee.Number(ee.List(esun).get(10)).divide(sum_esun);
    
    //caclulating the albedo at the top of the atmosphere (atoa) according formula 8
    
    var albedo = ee.Image().expression(
      'ome1*r1+ome2*r2+ome3*r3+ome4*r4+ome5*r5+ome6*r6+ome7*r7+ome8*r8+ome9*r9+ome10*r10+ome11*r11',{
        'r1':r1,
        'ome1':ee.Number(ome1),
         'r2':r2,
        'ome2':ee.Number(ome2),
         'r3':r3,
        'ome3':ee.Number(ome3),
         'r4':r4,
        'ome4':ee.Number(ome4),
         'r5':r5,
        'ome5':ee.Number(ome5),
         'r6':r6,
        'ome6':ee.Number(ome6),
        'r7':r7,
        'ome7':ee.Number(ome7),
         'r8':r8,
        'ome8':ee.Number(ome8),
         'r9':r9,
        'ome9':ee.Number(ome9),
         'r10':r10,
        'ome10':ee.Number(ome10),
          'r11':r11,
        'ome11':ee.Number(ome11),
      }).rename('albedo');
    return ee.Image(ele).addBands(albedo);
  });
  
  //4.A.computing the surface albedo (model F04).
  //αcorr = (αtoa − αpath_radiance)/τsw**2 (10)
  //αpath_radiance is the average portion of the incoming solar radiation across all
  //bands that is back-scattered to the satellite before it reaches the earths surface, and τsw
  //is the atmospheric transmissivity
  //Values for αpath_radiance range between 0.025 and 0.04 and for SEBAL I recommend a
  //value of 0.03 based on Bastiaanssen (2000)
  // τsw = 0.75 + 2 × 10-5 × z (11) // z is elevation
  
  //elevation from SRTM
  
 var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
 var elevation = SRTM.select('elevation').clip(Zim);

 dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
  
  var albedo =ee.Image(ele).select('albedo');
  var albedo_corr = ee.Image().expression(
    '(albedo - 0.03)/(0.75 + 2E-5*elevation)**2',{
     'albedo':albedo,
     'elevation':elevation
    }).rename('albedo_corr');
    
  return ee.Image(ele).addBands(albedo_corr);

 });
 
 //B. Incoming Shortwave radiation (Rs)
 // Rs = Gsc x cos0 x dr x x tsw // Gsc is the solar constant 1367, 0 = 90 - SUN ELEVATION
 
 dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
   
   
   var idx = dataset_list.indexOf(ele);
   
   var Rs = ee.Image().expression(
     '1367 * cos((90 - beta) * PI / 100) * dr * (0.75 + 2E-5 * elevation)',{
       'beta' :ee.Number(ee.Image(ele).get('SUN_ELEVATION')),
       'PI' :Math.PI,
       'dr' :ee.Number(ee.List(dr).get(idx)),
       'elevation':elevation
     }).rename('Rs');
     
     return ee.Image(ele).addBands([Rs]);
     
 });
  
  //C. Outgoing Longwave Radiation (RL)
  //1. Three commonly used vegetation indices are computed (model F05). Normalized
  //Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI), Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index (SAVI), and Leaf
  //Area Index (LAI) are computed using the reflectivity values found in model F02
  //NDVI = (ρ5 − ρ4) / (ρ 5 + ρ 4 )
  //SAVI = (1 + L) (ρ5 − ρ4 ) / (L + ρ5 + ρ4 )
  //computed for southern Idaho using the following empirical equation:
  //LAI = − ln((0.69 - SAVI)/0.59)/0.91
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var ndvi = ee.Image(ele).normalizedDifference(['ref5','ref4']).rename('ndvi');
    var L = 0.5; 
    var savi = ee.Image().expression(
      '(1+L)*(ref5 - ref4)/(L + ref5 +ref4)',{
        'ref4':ee.Image(ele).select('ref4'),
        'ref5':ee.Image(ele).select('ref5'),
        'L':L
      }).rename('savi');
   
   var lai = ee.Image().expression(
     '-log((0.69 - savi)/0.59)/0.91',{
     'savi':savi
     
     }).rename('lai');
   
    return ee.Image(ele).addBands([ndvi,savi,lai]);
  });


 //2. Surface emissivity (ε) is the ratio of the thermal energy radiated by the surface to the
  //thermal energy radiated by a blackbody at the same temperature. Two surface
  //emissivities are used in SEBAL.  
  //Enb is used in calculation of surface temperature (Ts) and E0 is used to calculate total
  //long wave radiation emission from the surface.
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var ndvi =ee.Image(ele).select('ndvi');
    var lai = ee.Image(ele).select('lai');
    var albedo =ee.Image(ele).select('albedo_corr');
    
    var Enb_bin1 = ndvi.gt(0).and(lai.lt(3)); // formula
    var Enb_bin2 = ndvi.gt(0).and(lai.gte(3)); // 0.98
    var Enb_bin3 =ndvi.lt(0).and(albedo.lt(0.47)); //water - 0.99
    var Enb_bin4 =ndvi.lt(0).and(albedo.gte(0.47)); // snow - 0.99
    
    var Enb = ee.Image().expression(
      'Enb_bin1*(0.97 + 0.0033 *LAI) + Enb_bin2 *0.98 + Enb_bin3*0.99 + Enb_bin4*0.99', {
       'Enb_bin1': Enb_bin1,
       'Enb_bin2':Enb_bin2,
      'Enb_bin3':Enb_bin3,
       'Enb_bin4':Enb_bin4,
       'LAI':lai
      }).rename('Enb');
      
    var Eo_bin1 = ndvi.gt(0).and(lai.lt(3)); // formula
    var Eo_bin2 = ndvi.gt(0).and(lai.gte(3)); // 0.98
    var Eo_bin3 =ndvi.lt(0).and(albedo.lt(0.47)); //water - 0.985
    var Eo_bin4 =ndvi.lt(0).and(albedo.gte(0.47)); // snow - 0.985

  var Eo =ee.Image().expression(
    'Eo_bin1 *(0.95 + 0.01 *LAI) + Eo_bin2 * 0.98 + Eo_bin3 *0.985 + Eo_bin4 *0.985',{
     'Eo_bin1': Eo_bin1,
     'Eo_bin2':Eo_bin2,
      'Eo_bin3':Eo_bin3,
      'Eo_bin4':Eo_bin4,
      'LAI':lai  
    }).rename('Eo');

  return ee.Image(ele).addBands([Enb, Eo]);
  });
  
  //3. The corrected thermal radiance from the surface (Rc) is calculated following Wukelic et al.(1989)
  //Rc = ((L10 - Rp)/tnb) - (1 - Enb)*Rsky 

  //Rsky = (1.807E-10*(Ta + 273.15)**4)*(1 - 0.26*exp(-7.77E-4*(273.15 - (Ta + 273.15))**2))

  //Values for Rp(path radiance) and tnb(narrow band transmissivity of air) require the use of an atmospheric radiation transfer simulation
  //model such as Modtran and radiosonde profiles representing the image and date. In the
  //absence of values for these terms, they can be ignored by setting Rp = 0 and τauNB = 1
  
  //So, Rc = L10  - (1 - Enb)*Rsky 

  //4. The surface temperature (Ts) is computed in model F07 using the following modified Plank equation
  //Ts = K2 / ln ((Enb*K1/Rc) + 1)
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var K1 =ee.Image(ele).get('K1_CONSTANT_BAND_10');
    var K2 =ee.Image(ele).get('K2_CONSTANT_BAND_10');
    
    
    var Ts = ee.Image().expression(
      '(K2 / log((Enb*K1/Rc) +1)) - 273.15',{
        'K2':ee.Number(K2),
        'K1':ee.Number(K1),
        'Enb':ee.Image(ele).select('Enb'),
        'Rc':ee.Image(ele).select('L10')
      }).rename('temperature');
      return ee.Algorithms.If(K1,ee.Image(ele).addBands(Ts),0);
  }).removeAll([0]);
  
  
    //5. The outgoing longwave radiation (Rl ) is computed (model F08). This is computed
  //using the Stefan-Boltzmann equation
  //Rl = E0*5.67E-8*Ts**4
  
  dataset_list = dataset_list.map(function(ele){
    
    var Rlo =ee.Image().expression(
      'Eo*5.67E-8*(Ts + 273.15)**4', {
      'Eo':ee.Image(ele).select('Eo'),
      'Ts':ee.Image(ele).select('temperature')
      }).rename('R_outgoing_longwave');
    return ee.Image(ele).addBands(Rlo);
  });

 
return dataset_list;

});

//I need to know where  farms are so, this function calculates the bounds for images for path/row [160, 43]. 

var imageBounds=ee.FeatureCollection(newDataset.map(function(ele){
  
  return ee.Feature(ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ele).first()).geometry());
}));

Map.addLayer(imageBounds, {}, 'image bounds');





//E. Incoming Longwave Radiation (RLi)
//RLi = Ea*5.67E-8*Tcold**4; assuming momentarily Tmin as Tcold
//τsw = 0.75 + 2E-5*elevation
//Values for RLi can range from 200 – 500 W/m2, depending on the location and time 
//of image

var newDataset = newDataset.map(function(ele){
  
  var idx_ele = newDataset.indexOf(ele);
  
  var pt = ee.Feature(points_list.get(idx_ele)).geometry();
  
  var addingRLi =ee.List(ele).map(function(e){
     var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
     var elevation = SRTM.select('elevation').clip(Zim);
    
    var Ta = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Image(e).select('temperature').sample(pt,30)).first()).get('temperature');
    
    var RLi =ee.Image().expression(
      '1.08*(-log(0.75 + 2E-5*elevation)**0.265)*5.67E-8*(Tcold + 273.15)**4',{
      'elevation':elevation,
      'Tcold':ee.Number(Ta)
    }).rename('RLi');
    return [ee.Image(e).addBands(RLi), Ta];
  });
  return addingRLi;
  
});

//At this point, the list newDataset is a list of lists where, for each date, contains an image and a temperature
//value. For later calculation of final Rn bands, I need a dataset with only images. For this reason I  create the
//newDataset2 where is taken the portion (id = 0) with only images. The portion with id = 1 contains the values of Ta (it
//is also individualized in corresponding tempInPoint function).
var newDataset2 = newDataset.map(function(ele) {
  var image = ee.List(ele).map(function(e) {
    return ee.List(e).get(0);
  });
  return image;
});

print('newDataset with incoming longwave radiation (RLi)', newDataset2);
 

var tempInPoint =newDataset.map(function(ele){
  
  var tempVal =ee.List(ele).map(function(e){
    
    return ee.List(e).get(1);
  });
    return tempVal;
  
});


print('temperature value in sebal points',tempInPoint);

//using a test layer for exploring RLi values

print ("here2" , newDataset2);

var newDataset2 = newDataset2.map(function (ele) {
  
    var addRn = ee.List(ele).map(function (e) {
      
      var Rn = ee.Image().expression(
        'Rs - albedo * Rs + RLi - RLo - (1 - E0)*RLi', {
        'albedo': ee.Image(e).select('albedo_corr'),
        'Rs': ee.Image(e).select('R_incoming_sh'),
        'RLi': ee.Image(e).select('RLi'),
        'RLo': ee.Image(e).select('R_outgoing_longwave'),
        'E0': ee.Image(e).select('Eo')
        }
        
      ).rename('Rn');
    
      return ee.Image(e).addBands(Rn);
    
  });
  return addRn;
});

print("newDataset2 with net Radiation (Rn)", newDataset2);
```

Here is my link for the entire code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/73f26aff0e9ca6c916d44b65fb3d838c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im trying to calculate Rn however im getting an error which states that, String (Error)
Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required.

Comment: This forum is best at tackling targeted questions. By distilling your issue to a concise code snippet, you'll not only enable us to assist you more effectively but might also discover the solution independently. Currently, your code spans nearly 700 lines, requiring substantial time and effort to debug—a commitment many here may hesitate to make. I recommend using print statements throughout your code and strategically commenting out sections to pinpoint the error source more efficiently. Best of luck in your troubleshooting process.